# Why the first child property is not getting applied to the second instance of the ol?

Tags: css, html-lists

See what happens with firebug or inspect element...

The two OL are under two different IDs (#secondary_navigation and #secondary_navigation_bottom), however the properties assigned to the first child of both dependent OL do not get applied to the second instance...

As you can see in this example I linked, the first child in the second OL is not red but the desired effect would be that red too.

Any clue on what's wrong?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please don't make life difficult for us - if the system tells you to include code from the fiddle within your question, do that, not make the link unclickable.

Comment: I couldn't understand what it meant, I tried multiple times and I still couldn't post, that's why I made it unlinkable. I'm a newbie of this site, sorry xD

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting your code. I also undeleted a couple of your questions including this one because I notice you were deleting them after they were answered - don't do that, as that actually nudges you closer to a ban from asking new questions. Use the checkmark beneath the post score to mark an answer to your question accepted instead - that's how we say thanks on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will not work because the li under the second old does not have a "first" class:

```
#secondary_navigation #breadcrumb li.first a span, #secondary_navigation_bottom #breadcrumb li.first a span{
    color: red;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
    border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
}
```

So just add a "first" class to the li of the second item. Here's a working JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/judeosborn/YhLxm/

Line 15 should looks like this:

Notice there is now a "first" class. That isn't there on your JSFiddle.

Comment: Was so easy. My bad! Thank you!